# VideoView can't play video from InputStream

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm just downloading the video file using retrofit and converting it into tempFile, but after converting it the Video can't play.

This is what I did.

```
@Streaming
@GET("media/attachment")
fun getAttachmentFromMedia(): Observable<ResponseBody>


fun getAttachment() {
    getApi().getAttachmentFromMedia()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            {
                if (fileType.contains("image")) { 
                    //.. some stuff here
                } else if (fileType.contains("video")) {
                    val tmpFile = File.createTempFile("default", ".mp4")
                    tmpFile.deleteOnExit()

                    try {
                        val output = FileOutputStream(tmpFile)
                        var read = 0
                        output.use { _ ->
                            val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)
                            while (it.byteStream().read(buffer).let { read = it; read != -1 }) {
                                output.write(buffer, 0, read)
                            }
                            output.flush()
                        }
                    } finally {
                        it.byteStream().close()

                        val mediaController = MediaController(holder.itemView.context)
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.videoView)
                        holder.videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)

                        holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(tmpFile))
                        holder.videoView.start()

                        holder.videoView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "getAttachment failed", it)
            }
        )
}
```

[image]

This code is working when the attachment is image, but in video, I really don't know why the video is not playing.

Also I don't know why the app is freezing for a moment when calling this `getAttachmentFromMedia()` api.

Am I doing correct here, or should I change something?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you try to play the mp4 file on video players?

Comment: You mean I add the `holder.videoView.start()` on my code?

Comment: Yes sir, but this is the result. still popping https://imgur.com/a/DR2duEo
and the video is not working well?

Comment: No I mean do you try play the mp4 file (that you downloaded from the server) by using any video players on you phone to make sure it's a valid video file.

Comment: I didn't try to play the file from any video player, since I'm just creating a temporary file for the video.

Comment: Because you are copying a file from an inputstream on UI thread, that why you see the app freeze in a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179946/discussion-between-son-truong-and-dotgitignore).

Comment: are you sure that your video is in ANdroid-supported format?

Comment: yes, I don't know but the video is now working well, The video size is around 6mb and I just increase the size of the `buffer` from `val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)` to `val buffer = ByteArray(10 * 1024)` , still I really don't know if it is good.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the file in your device, play video from the file_path like this.

Put the below code in your finally block.

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mFilePath));
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController );
videoView.start();
```

Play video directly from video_url like this.

```
          try {
                pDialog.show();
                MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
                mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
                videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                videoview.setVideoURI(video);
                videoview.requestFocus();
                videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       pDialog.dismiss();
                       videoview.start();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   VideoView videoView;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.ViewVideo);


        String videopath = "android.resource://com.example.cloudanalogy.play_video/"+R.raw.a; //com.example.cloudanalogy.play_video this is my package name,and inside the raw file a.mp4 video
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(videopath);
        videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        videoView.start();
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);


    }
}
```

Comment: any problem to use this code so please let me know.Thanks You

Comment: He asked how to play from stream, Not from system path, URI etc. Thanks